# Upload image from C# program to SAP WSDL Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, upload, wsdl

I would like to develop a C# app that uploads binary files (pdf/jpg) to an (SAP) WSDL WebService. What datatype should I use for this. Does someone has some examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WCF to bind to the SAP service, and transport binary files between the two. Here are some links to start you off:

[SO thread discussion on Binary Encoding in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282819/serialize-wcf-message-in-a-binary-way-and-not-as-a-soap-message)

[Working with Binary Data (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473426.aspx)

[WCF BizTalk SAP Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185529%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx)

Let us know if you have a specific problem with any of these approaches.